# Angular POST to Web API

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

So I am trying to create a register page with my existing web API.
There are a few post methods on the **AccountController**, but I have commented them all out apart from 2. Here is what they look like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles all account related functions.
/// </summary>
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private const string LocalLoginProvider = "Local";

    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private readonly UserService<User> service;
    private readonly UserLoginService userLoginService;
    private readonly RoleService<User> roleService;
    private readonly ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat;

    /// <summary>
    /// Parameterless Constructor which references the startup config auth options access token format.
    /// </summary>
    public AccountController()
        : this(StartupConfig.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor with the access token format parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="accessTokenFormat">The parameter for specifying the access token format.</param>
    public AccountController(ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork<DatabaseContext>();
        this.service = new UserService<User>(this.unitOfWork, false, true);
        this.userLoginService = new UserLoginService(this.unitOfWork);
        this.roleService = new RoleService<User>(this.unitOfWork);
        this.accessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
    }

    // POST api/account/register
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers a new user with the system.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The model representing the user.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(r3plica.Identity.IdentityResult))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var user = new User
        {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email
        };

        var result = await service.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        var errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

        if (errorResult != null)
            return errorResult;

        await this.unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(user.Id);
    }

    // POST api/account/logout
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs the current user out.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Logout")]
    public IHttpActionResult Logout()
    {
        Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

and my angular controller looks like this:

```
.controller('RegisterController', ['$state', 'Api', function ($state, api) {
    var self = this;

    self.model = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: ''
    };

    self.register = function () {
        api.post('account/register', self.model).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function (error) {
            alert('error!');
        });
    };
}]);
```

If I comment out the **Logout** function in my **AccountController**, then try to register, it registers fine and all the fields are populated and correct.
If I uncomment **Logout** and send the same form, I get an error:

> > Multiple actions were found that match the request:
> >
> > Register on type AccountController
> >
> > Logout on type AccountController

As you can see **Logout** is parameterless, so I am not sure why I am getting this error. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks fine. In your application start, have you configured web api in the following way: GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)?

Comment: If I comment out the Logout function it works perfectly.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is a very important line of code that is required in your **WebApiConfig**

> > config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

Without this, having a route set up would be ignored, so saying that this bit of code:

```
[Route("Register")]
```

would not be hit. Because both **Register** and **Logout** were decorated with **[HttpPost]**, it meant that they were being treated as the same.